# Easier way to change classes on multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am writing a page with a lot of "tabs" and each of them has a piece of text that should become visible when you click on the tab.

So far no problems and I achieved this by using "clickfunction" and "add/ removeClass".
But the thing now is that there are alot of tabs being add to the page and my JS file really gets cluttered with slightly different references. Is there an easier and more efficient way to do this?
My code looks like this:

**The tab:**

```
<li id="a2b" class="blok roze">
    <i class="fa fa-bus"><span>A2B Transfers</span></i>
</li>
```

**The content for the tab:**

```
<div class="a2b sysBox nonVisible">
    <h3>A2B Transfers</h3>
    <p>Informatie volgt binnenkort</p>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="btnBox">
        <a href="http://www.a2btransfers.com/" target="_blank">
            <div class="btnSystem">Ga naar A2B Travel</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And one of the JS pieces:**

```
$('#vakantieveilingen').click(function() {
    $('.vakantieveilingen').removeClass('nonVisible').addClass('visible');
    $('.a2b').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.bedsonline').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.holidaytaxis').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.hotelbeds').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.actievandedag').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.alturabeds').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.eazzypark').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.europeesche').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.exclusivehotels').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.expedia').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.floow').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.groupon').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.lmx').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.med').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.miki').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.parkfly').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.taxibreburg').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.thomascook').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.transavia').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
    $('.jumbo').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
});
```

I hope someone knows how to handle this well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to scale this all down to one click handler for all tabs by using common classes and attributes

i'm not sure what the ID's in selector `$('#vakantieveilingen')` refer to in your html but your end result should be fairly simple like:

```
$('.blok').click(function(){
   var targetClass= '.' + this.id;
   // hide all content blocks
   $('.sysBox').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible');
   // show content related to this tab
   $(targetClass).removeClass('nonVisible').addClass('visible')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group jQuery selector as:

```
$('.thomascook, .transavia, .jumbo').removeClass('visible').addClass('nonVisible'); });
```

to shorten the JS code.